# How to answer the question from Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 problem 34

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to prove that  $$\lim_{x\to 0+} f(\frac{1}{x}) =  \lim_{x\to ∞}f(x)$$

I know the definition of the left side that is:

- ∀ ε > 0 ∃ δ > 0: if 0 < x < δ  then |$f(\frac{1}{x})$ -L| <ε

And I want to prove that is the same as:

- ∀ ε > 0 ∃ N > 0: if x > N  then |f(x)-L| <ε

I am a beginner so I apologize if thi is too basic.

Comment: In the first one you want $f(1/x)$ not $f(x)$ don't you.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake, thank you

Comment: It suffices to prove that for $x\to0^+ \implies \frac1x \to \infty$, are you forced to use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: Yes, I must use that definition because Spivak (and my teacher) asks for that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can take $N$ as you stated, then take $0<\delta<\frac{1}{N}$, then $\frac{1}{\delta}>N$ so if $|x|<\delta$, you have $|\frac{1}{x}|>\frac{1}{\delta}>N$.

And you need to consider the situation that $f$ diverges.

Comment: what I did is to take δ= 1/N

I don't know why I would suppose δ <  1/N

Comment: You can take $\delta = 1/N$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
if 
$$
0<|x|<\epsilon\implies \left|\frac{1}{x} \right|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}
$$
You may make the quantity on the far left as large as you want by taking $\epsilon$ small.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late in answering this question but as I'm solving Spivak Calculus now and came across this question, I thought to answer it.

Now, as you have rightly written in the definition, let $\lim_{x\to ∞}f(x)=L$ then, for every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is $x$ such that for all $x \gt N \implies |f(x) - L| \lt \epsilon$

Let $\frac{1}{\delta} = N$

Now,  $0 \lt x \lt \delta \implies {\frac{1}{x}} \gt \frac{1}{\delta} \implies \frac{1}{x} \gt N \implies  |f(\frac{1}{x}) - L| \lt \epsilon $

Hence  $0 \lt x \lt \delta \implies |f(\frac{1}{x}) - L| \lt \epsilon $ which means $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=L$

Comment: But are you not assuming that L is a real number? What would happen if these are infinite limits, for example conisder $f(x)=1/x)$.